# how to manipulate jquery offset results

Tags: jquery

Hi I have an image who's position I get and store to a variable using

```
var position = $(".portfolio-items a").offset();
```

but for some reason it returns

```
Object { top=1227.5, left=416.5}
```

How would I go about rounding it up and adding the px on the end so that I can then assign it to a new element to place it over the top of the current one?

Thanks.

I've uploaded the site to www.pixelcoding.co.uk so that you can see where the problem is now.  When you click on the AJLComputers portfolio link the new image should be displayed over the old one but it is off by about 200pxs vertically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use `Math.round()` on the returned positions:

```
var position = $(".portfolio-items a").offset(),
    top = Math.round(position.top) + 'px',
    left = Math.round(position.left) + 'px';
```

This will always round appropriately (so `0.4` rounds *down* to `0`, `0.5` rounds *up* to `1`); if you always want to round up then you can use `Math.ceil()` in place of `Math.round()`:

```
var position = $(".portfolio-items a").offset(),
    top = Math.cel(position.top) + 'px',
    left = Math.ceil(position.left) + 'px';
```

There's also `Math.floor()` which, as you might imagine, always rounds *down* to the integer.

But while you *can* use the functions, it's not necessary to do so, since jQuery can, and will, use them as-is.

References:

- [`Math.ceil()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil).
- [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor).
- [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round).

Comment: This works but I have another problem, the new image I'm trying to overlay is static and that means I need to remove the page offset, I tried it with

    $(document).scrollTop();

but it's still not in the correct position, am I missing something?

Comment: You're missing the code in your question. Add the [*relevant*/sscce](http://sscce.org/) JavaScript, HTML and CSS. Provide a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) if you can. Then we can see what's happening. Explain what you *want* to happen, and what's going wrong.

Comment: I've uploaded the website to www.pixelcoding.co.uk if you click on the first portfolio image (AJL Computers) then you'll see what happens, the new image should appear in the same place as the old one but it's coming up about 200px too low.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the object as-is.

```
var position = $(".portfolio-items a").offset();
$( '#new-item' ).offset( position );
```

Comment: I tried that and the object doesn't show on the page, for some reason it gets top: -316px; left: 416.5px;

Comment: Then it seems the problem lies elsewhere. Can you reproduce your problem with a [minimal/sscce](http://sscce.org/) [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/)?